# Keyerror when adding a column to a Dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

Pandas DataFrame is not really accepting adding a second column, and I cannot really troubleshoot the issue. I am trying to display Moving Averages. The code works fine just for the first one (MA_9), and gives me error as soon I try to add additional MA (MA_20).

Is it not possible in this case to add more than one column?

The code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as pdr
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


symbol = 'GOOG.US'
start = '20140314'
end = '20180414'
google = pdr.DataReader(symbol, 'stooq', start, end)
print(google.head())

google_close = pd.DataFrame(google.Close)
print(google_close.last_valid_index)
google_close['MA_9'] = google_close.rolling(9).mean()
google_close['MA_20'] = google_close.rolling(20).mean()
# google_close['MA_60'] = google_close.rolling(60).mean()
# print(google_close)
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
plt.grid(True)

# display MA's
plt.plot(google_close['Close'], label='Google_Cls')
plt.plot(google_close['MA_9'], label='MA 9 day')
plt.plot(google_close['MA_20'], label='MA 20 day')
# plt.plot(google_close['MA_60'], label='MA 60 day')
plt.legend(loc=2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Would be easier to help if error messages were included, but it looks like there is an answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Please update your code as below and then it should work:

```
google_close['MA_9'] = google_close.Close.rolling(9).mean()
google_close['MA_20'] = google_close.Close.rolling(20).mean()
```

Initially there was only one column data of Close so your old code `google_close['MA_9'] = google_close.rolling(9).mean()` worked but after this line of code now it has two column and so it does not know which data you are trying to mean. So updating with the column details of data you wanted to mean, it works `google_close['MA_20'] = google_close.Close.rolling(20).mean()`

Comment: Everything makes sense now, Thank you